# Handsontable autocomplete items sorting

Tags: javascript, handsontable

Hi i have a problem with sorting in autocomplete column type. When i open dropdown for all items without searching anything i get results sorted as i wanted, but when i start typing into cell i get results but they are sorted from shortest string to longest string. Is it possible to disable this sorting and get results sorted the same way as i provide them to `process` function?

Example here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/wj5vdnt5/3/

when i don't type anything i have sorted correct way
[image: when i don't type anything i have sorted correct way]

when i start typing sorting from shortest tot longest
[image: when i start typing sorting from shortest tot longest]

Comment: Before you type they are sorted by recency. After they are sorted alphabetically. Not by length but shorter strings that are prefixes of longer ones do come before their extensions.

Comment: Ok, but is there a way to disable this sorting? I want to sort them by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Just disable [`sortByRelevance`](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/Options.html#sortByRelevance) for your autocomplete cell type.

```
columns: [
  {
    type: 'autocomplete',
    source: [ ... ],
    sortByRelevance: false
  }
]
```

Comment: `sortByRelevance` allows to use another sort order than by relevance. But it is not sufficient because even if we still have highlights of searched strings we lose the filtering on values.
To avoid that, it may help to give a custom filtering function to the source property instead of a raw array.